# Please tell me how to delete Facelistid in FaceAPI at once

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am currently using FaceAPI, but I'd like to delete FacelistIds created there at once.
Although it was possible to delete one by one from the following manual, since it is impossible to delete one thing with more than 1000 items, please let me know if you know how to delete all at once.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @Ayumu Any update on this? Did the answer help? Please select 'Propose as answer' if it helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the API reference in the API documentation for large facelist here:
https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/5a1580d5d2de3616c086f2cd

It says -

LargeFaceList - Delete

Delete a specified large face list. The related face images in the large face list will be deleted, too.

Http Method
DELETE

curl -v -X DELETE "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/largefacelists/{largeFaceListId}"
-H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: {subscription key}"

Answer (score 0):

For FaceList, you can use [FaceList - Delete](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039524f) to delte the whole FaceList. The related face images in the face list will be deleted, too.